# python search function not working

Tags: python

I need help with part of python code. I have search function which will search for string in file, and retrun it if found, or give Error dialog if not found. Also after Error dialog is closed, give user right to enter correct value. I did't put whole code, but basicly /tmp/ARNE/final1 file looks like:

```
siu43543, RTWAURT
siu34544, RYAKCCD
```

and if user enters name for example siu43543, it will reaturn RTWAURT, or give error dialog, and wait for correct value. So my function needs to give error dialog, or the value, if found.

```
def search(VAR,VAR1):
    global linese
    global linese1
    with open("/tmp/ARNE/final1", 'r') as file:
       for line in file:
              var=re.search(VAR, line)
              if var:
                  linese = line.split(',')[0]
              else:
                  tkMessageBox.showinfo("ERROR", "MISSING ELEMENT") 
                  return Exception 

              var11=re.search(VAR1, line)
              if var1:
                  linese1 = line.split(',')[1] 
              else: 
                  tkMessageBox.showinfo("ERROR", "MISSING PARENT")
                  return Exception      
    return linese
    return linese1 

try:
    search(line1,line1) 
except Exception:
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If file all time the same there is no need to put open file command into function. The power of python is arrays so I'd like to offer read all file into array and than search in array's elements:

```
D1=[]
D2=[]
with open("/tmp/ARNE/final1", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        i,j=line.split(",")
        D1.append(i)
        D2.append(j)
def var_search(VAR,VAR1):
    if VAR in D1:
        ....
    if VAR1 in D2:
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rest of your codes are all right then i think the lines `linese = line.split(',')[0]` and `linese1 = line.split(',')[1]` are making the problem. As you need to `return` the word after `,` from the file `/tmp/ARNE/final1` the following should do the job.

In case of `var`:

```
linese = line.split()[1]
return linese #This will return `RTWAURT` if condition is satisfied
```

Likewise for `var1`:

```
linese1 = line.split()[1]
return liense1 #This will return `RYAKCCD` if condition is satisfied
```

Here is the example:

```
line = "siu43543, RTWAURT"
```

Now using your code that will `split` on comma(`,`) and you are taking the value at `index 0` i.e. `line.split(',')[0]` we have:

```
>>> line.split(',')[0]
'siu43543'
```

which is not you want.

Now using what i have used that will `split` on any whitespace character (default behaviour) and we are interested in the value at `index 1` i.e. `line.split()[1]`:

```
>>> line.split()[1]
'RTWAURT'
```

Exactly what you want to `return`.

Comment: ok, but if user gives wrong input which is not in file, I get error, that's why I need some checks to see if input is correct.

Comment: @user3319356: I have sorted out the issue with your `re.search()` usage, as your question title specifically suggests that. If you want some other modifications then you should ask a new question with a proper title and full coding.